# TSQL Group by Order by

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The following is an actual interview question that I actually failed. Just curious what is the correct answer.

Given the following tables:

```
SELECT * FROM users;

user_id  username
1        John Doe                                                                                            
2        Jane Don                                                                                            
3        Alice Jones                                                                                         
4        Lisa Romero

SELECT * FROM training_details;

user_training_id  user_id  training_id  training_date
1                 1        1            "2015-08-02"
2                 2        1            "2015-08-03"
3                 3        2            "2015-08-02"
4                 4        2            "2015-08-04"
5                 2        2            "2015-08-03"
6                 1        1            "2015-08-02"
7                 3        2            "2015-08-04"
8                 4        3            "2015-08-03"
9                 1        4            "2015-08-03"
10                3        1            "2015-08-02"
11                4        2            "2015-08-04"
12                3        2            "2015-08-02"
13                1        1            "2015-08-02"
14                4        3            "2015-08-03"
```

Write a query to to get the list of users who took the a training lesson more than once in the same day, grouped by user and training lesson, each ordered from the most recent lesson date to oldest date.

Comment: So, what was your suggested solution?

Comment: I didn't knew that you can use count(*) in the having clause this way and basically I did not suggested an answer before the answering time elapsed

Comment: The point of the having clause it to enable you to add a filter on the already grouped records. this is quite a basic concept in sql.

Comment: Yes but I thought you can filter the already grouped records by the values of the fields used in the group by clause like eg "having username like ..." I did not knew you can use an aggregate function like count(*) > 1 in the having clause and the resulting filter to be "number of records with the same training date and same user name greater than one" I thought that if I use count(*) in the having clause it will always be the total number of records after the grouping and not the count of the subset of records in each group. Anyway it all make sense now thanks again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, it should be something like this:

```
SELECT username, tranning_date
FROM users u
INNER JOIN training_details t ON(u.user_id = t.user_id)
GROUP BY username, tranning_date
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY username, tranning_date DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
`SELECT u.USERNAME, t.USER_ID, t.TRAINING_DATE, COUNT(t.TRAINING_ID) 
 FROM training_details t JOIN USERS u ON (u.id = t.user_id)
 GROUP BY u.USERNAME,t.USER_ID, t.TRAINING_ID, t.TRAINING_DATE
 HAVING COUNT(t.TRAINING_ID)>1
 ORDER BY t.TRAINING_DATE DESC;`


Results => 

"USERNAME",     "USER_ID","TRAINING_DATE","COUNT(T.TRAINING_ID)"
"Lisa Romero",   4,         08-04-2015,        2
"Lisa Romero",   4,         08-03-2015,        2
"John Doe",      1,         08-02-2015,        3
"Alice Jones",   3,         08-02-2015,        2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select
   u.user_id,
   username,
   training_id,
   training_date,
   count (user_training_id) AS count
From users u JOIN training_details t ON t.user_id= u.user_id
Group By user_id, 
         username, 
         training_id,
         training_date
Having count(user_training_ id) > 1
Order By training_date DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT username, training_date ,  count(*) as count
FROM users u
INNER JOIN training_details t ON(u.user_id = t.user_id)
GROUP BY username, training_date
having count(*) > 1
ORDER BY username,training_date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Select username, training_Date
from users, training _details
where
users.user_id=training_details.user_id
group by username
having count(Training _id)>1
order by training_Date desc;

Comment: Just a copy from all other answers. Just not formatted good, and using old style `join`s.